# Why is saving a byte object to a file faster than saving it to a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, file

Let's say I have a following byte object/string/array (not sure of the name for this, but in my specific case it represents an image):

```
content = b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x08\x03\x00\x00\x00\xc3\xa6$\xc8\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x0f\x01\xb9\x8f\x00\x00\x00\x03PLTE\x00\x00\x00\xa7z=\xda\x00\x00\x00\x01tRNS\x00@\xe6\xd8f\x00\x00\x01\x16IDATx\xda\xed\xfd\xc1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03!\x9c?\xf5\xbe\x83(\x92\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0\x0c\x02<\x00\x017\x93\x98\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
```

If I want to save this to a file I'd just do this:

```
file = open('img.png', 'wb')
file.write(content)
file.close()
```

If I wanted to use an array (array of arrays basically since I have multiple images) I'd do this:

```
img = np.array(Image.open(io.BytesIO(content)))
arr.append(img)
```

However, execution of the array code takes `~0.0008` seconds and the execution of the array code takes `~0.0001` seconds. Even extended to 400+ files the difference ends up being ~20-30 seconds.

My questions are basically:

1. **Is this performance difference expected?**
2. **Are there any benefits to using the array approach as I am manipulating/changing the said files/images afterwards (could working with arrays be faster?) ?**

Comment: There are a lot of conversions going on in the array example, including decompressing your PNG file into a byte array that is much larger than the original PNG.  You are comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks. I suspected so, but is there even a different way to create an array in a different way in this case? For my use-case I'd need an array of shape ```array([[0, 0, 0, 0], ... [0, 0, 0, 0]]``` where each row represents an RGBA pixel.

Comment: That's what your second snippet does.  The first doesn't solve your problem, so it's performance is not relevant.

Comment: Okay I see, I'll have to check whether reading from a file causes a performance dip later on. I presume in the end the performance will be pretty similar for both approaches as there is no escaping this conversion in my case. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Honestly, if you are doing image processing, that time is going to dwarf the minor overhead of reading and decoding the image.